# TYPO3: indexed_search and language

Tags: configuration, typo3, multilingual

If I make a search with indexed_search the page has contents like

```
Search for: xxx
Page 1
Page x
Next >
Size
Created
```

but the language of the page is another one. This is true for the default language (german) and another language (slovenski). The configuration of the plugin has either the Language `Default` or `Slovenski`.

I have set the `config.language` parameter

```
config {
    linkVars = L
    sys_language_mode = content_fallback
    sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
    sys_language_uid = 0
    language = de
    locale_all = de_DE
}

[globalVar = GP:L=]
config {
  sys_language_uid = 0
  language = de_DE
  local_all = de_DE
  htmlTag_langKey = de
}
[global]

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config {
    sys_language_uid = 1
    language = en
    locale_all = en_EN
}
[global]

[globalVar = GP:L=2]
config {
     sys_language_uid = 2
     language = it
     local_all = it_IT
}
[global]

[globalVar = GP:L=3]
config {
     sys_language_uid = 3
     language = sl
     local_all = sl_SL
}
[global]
```

In translation handling I select my languages and click "Check status against repository". But I only get `N/A` for all entries.

In typo3conf/l10n/de/indexed_search/pi I see a `de.locallang.xml`. If it is the right file the file is existing, but always the infos of the search results are displayed in English. What is wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Which type of problem do you have?:

1. Is the wording of the text that comes with the search plugin (field
   label, explanation text) in the wrong language
2. or are you getting results from content in languages that do not match the current
   language?

To solve 1.: 
Ctrl-select all needed languages in "Extension Manager" -> "Translation handling". Then click "Update from repository" and wait until all language files for all extensions have been downloaded.

To solve 2.: 
Add a language dependent setting for  plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang  to your TS-Setup.

Your setup has multiple flaws by the way, so I give you a complete example for TS-Setup here:

```
# German language
config.sys_language_uid = 0
config.language = de
config.htmlTag_langKey = de-DE
# the following can differ depending on server OS, e.g. "de_DE.UTF8" on Linux or "german" on Windows:
config.locale_all = de_DE
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 0

# English language
[globalVar = GP:L=1]
  config.sys_language_uid = 1
  config.language = en
  config.htmlTag_langKey = en-US
  config.locale_all = en_US
  plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 1
[global]

# Italian language
[globalVar = GP:L=2]
  config.sys_language_uid = 2
  config.language = it
  config.htmlTag_langKey = it-IT
  config.locale_all = it_IT
  plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 2
[global]
```

Comment: The solution for problem 2 (content in languages that do not match the current language) doesnt seem to work in typo3-7.6 (indexed_search 7.6.0). Any chance to update the question?

Answer (score 6):

On TYPO3 7.6 i have to set `plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.languageUid =` 
to get results from a specific language

Answer (score 3):

In Typo3 8.7.9 I had to use

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch_pi2.settings.defaultOptions.languageUid < config.sys_language_uid
```

Note the "_pi2" !!!

Comment: Works not really: Searching in L=0 shows results from L=0 AND L=1 - But searching in L=1 shows only results from L=1. Seems to be a realURL issue, as without realURL it works perfect. Might depend on L=0 is www.domain.tld (no pagep path for default language) and L=1 is www.domain.tld/en/.

Comment: @JKB - have you set a default value for config.sys_language_uid ?

Comment: In my case i had to set "plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.languageUid" exactly three times: Once as default with "0", and then twice by a condition for L=0 and L=1. For any reasons the default value must be set, otherwise search is performed for "any languages"

Comment: This worked after setting both, ´plugin.tx_indexedsearch_pi2.settings.defaultOptions.languageUid´ and ´plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.languageUid´ to the specific language uid

Answer (score 3):

For TYPO3 V9 LTS, in TYPOSCRIPT Setup :

```
# Default Language
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.languageUid = 0

# English US
[siteLanguage("locale") == "en_US.UTF-8"]
    plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.languageUid = 0

# French
[siteLanguage("locale") == "fr_FR.UTF-8"]
    plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.languageUid = 1

[END]
```