# indexed_search shows content from different languages

Tags: search, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, indexed

I have indexed_search 7.6.0 installed and have the problem, that it shows content from different languages.

In this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713301/2481955 
Is a solution for this (look at `To solve 2.:`), but it seems this does not work in typo3 7.6

This is my Typoscript for the english language:

```
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
    config {
      htmlTag_langKey = 2
      sys_language_uid = 2
      language = en
      locale_all = en_EN
      sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
      sys_language_mode = strict
    }
      lib.language.value = 2

    plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 2
[global]
```

I cleaned all cash and all indexes. But as soon as a I call a page in another language and then search in the english language (`2`) this page of the wrong language will show up as a search result again.

Comment: Check your form in the template for indexed search. It should have something like `<input name="tx_indexedsearch[lang]" value="###ACTLANG###" type="hidden">`

Comment: @DmitryDulepov Yes thanks! I have a custom template and did not set the value for this field. The field is called `tx_indexedsearch_pi2[search][languageUid]`. For the default template this field gets filled with `{searchParams.languageUid}`. Do you know where to set this searchParam?

Comment: The searchParam is being set in the SearchController -> searchAction, so it should be set for your template the same way as for the default template, unless you did overwrite the action as well. In case you are using a partial, make sure to forward this information there. An easy way to check would be just to revert back to default template and check if the search works properly with that one.

Answer (score 2):

The configuration has changed.

Old:

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 2
```

New:

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.languageUid = 2
```

Example:

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.languageUid < page.config.sys_language_uid
```

... or ...

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.languageUid < config.sys_language_uid
```

... depending on if your language is configured in `page.config.sys_language_uid` or just `config.sys_language_uid`.

For more options have a look at the default configuration in /typo3_src/typo3/sysext/indexed_search/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt